# criba de eratóstenes para números grandes

Tags: c, optimización

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de optimización de código y tengo que optimizar el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void show_primes(int *primes, int max){
    int cont;
    int aux;
    for(cont=0; cont<max-1; cont=cont+1){
        if(primes[cont] == 1){
            aux = cont + 2;
            printf("%d", aux);
            printf(" ");                
        }
    }
}
int is_prime(int number){
    int prime=1;//por defecto es primo
    int divisors=2;
    while(divisors<number  && prime!=0)
    {
        if(number%divisors==0){
            prime = 0;
        }
        divisors++;
    }
    return prime;
}
int main()
{
    //Se entiende que el usuario va a introducir datos legitimos, por lo que 
    //no voy a comprobar si los datos de entrada pueden provocar una excepcion 
    //para ahorrar tiempo en el desarrollo de la practica dado que el objeto
    //de la practica no consiste en hacer un software robusto, si no optimo.
    int max = 518103; //introducir el numero maximo para la criba
    int cont;
    int primes[max];
    for(cont=0; cont<max-1; cont=cont+1){
        primes[cont] = is_prime(cont+2); //1 si es primo 0 si no
    }
    show_primes(primes,max);
    return 0;
}
```

Actualmente, mi algoritmo (está poco optimizado a propósito) solo es capaz de calcular hasta 518103 números de la criba.

Tengo que ser capaz de optimizarlo para que calcule números superiores a 2^31.

**He intentado utilizar `malloc` y `unsigned long int`, pero llega al mismo número máximo y tarda lo mismo.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void show_primes(unsigned long int *primes, unsigned long int max){
    unsigned long int cont;
    unsigned long int aux;
    for(cont=0; cont<max-1; cont=cont+1){
        if(primes[cont] == 1){
            aux = cont + 2;
            printf("%d", aux);
            printf(" ");                
        }
    }
}
int is_prime(unsigned long int number){
    int prime=1;//por defecto es primo
    unsigned long int divisors=2;
    while(divisors<number  && prime!=0)
    {
        if(number%divisors==0){
            prime = 0;
        }
        divisors++;
    }
    return prime;
}
int main()
{
    //Se entiende que el usuario va a introducir datos legitimos, por lo que 
    //no voy a comprobar si los datos de entrada pueden provocar una excepcion 
    //para ahorrar tiempo en el desarrollo de la practica dado que el objeto
    //de la practica no consiste en hacer un software robusto, si no optimo.
    unsigned long int *primes;
    unsigned long int max = 518103; //introducir el numero maximo para la criba - 518103
    primes = (unsigned long int *)calloc( max, sizeof( unsigned long int ) );
//      if( puntero != NULL ){
//          printf( "Allocated\n" );
//      }else{
//              printf( "Can't allocate memory\n" );
//          }
    unsigned long int cont;
    for(cont=0; cont<max-1; cont=cont+1){
        primes[cont] = is_prime(cont+2); //1 si es primo 0 si no
    }
    show_primes(primes,max);
    free(primes);
    return 0;
}
```

Además, no puedo eliminar los números no primos de la lista, por lo que puedo optimizar el tiempo más, pero yo de momento quiero optimizar la memoria.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

PD: Se que hay soluciones ya implementadas y óptimas, pero tiene que ser hecho por mi para que no lo consideren plagio.

Muchas gracias

Comment: "*Actualmente, […] solo es capaz de calcular hasta 518103 […] Tengo que ser capaz de optimizarlo para que calcule números superiores a 2^31*". Eso no es una optimización, al menos con los términos que la describes ¿Por qué el programa tiene un límite? ¿Qué te impide superarlo?

Comment: El espacio en memoria, se supone que no calcula más de ese número porque el pc se queda sin memoria

Comment: ¿No puedes hacer el cálculo por bloques en lugar de hacerlo todo de golpe?

Comment: Sí, en eso consiste el ejercicio, pero no se hacerlo

Comment: ¿No has pensado en hacer una función que reciba *inicio* y *final* del cálculo?

Comment: No me ha quedado muy claro... ¿no puedes borrar los números no primos?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no entiendo a qué te refieres.

Comment: @itsnesky no puedo, tengo que "tacharlos" no eliminarlos

Comment: @XBoss viendo el código de `main`, recorres números desde `0` a `max - 1`. Pon todo ese código en una función y pasa como parámetros lo que quieres que sea el inicio y lo que quieres que sea el final… y lo llamas con diferentes rangos.

Comment: El tamaño máximo de un array está determinado por la cantidad de memoria a la que un programa puede acceder. En un sistema de `32 bits`, la cantidad máxima de memoria que puede ser direccionada por un puntero es `2^32 bytes`, que son `4 gigabytes`. El límite real puede ser menor, dependiendo de los detalles de implementación del sistema operativo. Lo mismo para un sistema de `64 bits`, la cantidad máxima de memoria que puede ser direccionada por un puntero es `2^64 bytes`.

Comment: Me confunde que dices: debe devolver una lista con todos los números del 2 hasta N, y en la misma deben estar *¿tachados?* los números compuestos. Sin embargo tu programa devuelve una lista que incluye sólo números primos y ningún compuesto. ¿Qué sentido tiene devolver una lista con una gran cantidad de elementos *tachados*? No estoy seguro de la proporción, pero me atrevo a decir que el desperdicio de memoria de dicha lista es absurdo. En mi ordenador tu algoritmo devuelve el resultado en aprox. 107 segundos, mi algoritmo lo hace en 11 segundos (sin optimizar) para el mismo valor (N=518103).

Comment: Mauricio, yo solo estoy mostrando los números primos, pero tengo que almacenarlos todos, cuando me funcione, mostraré todos los números, tanto primos como no primos, igual que la criba.

Comment: Por último, dices: ***Se que hay soluciones ya implementadas y óptimas, pero tiene que ser hecho por mi para que no lo consideren plagio.*** Si respondo con mi código tampoco podrías usarlo, ya que se consideraría plagio también. Ahora, si respondo dando una explicación del proceso ¿crees que sería suficiente para que armes el algoritmo tuyo a partir de la lógica mía? ¿O eso también se podría considerar plagio? Es que el tema del plagio es muy delicado y amplio si te lo han puesto como norma para tu algoritmo.

Comment: @MauricioContreras puedo recibir ayuda para mi algoritmo, por lo que si muestras tu algoritmo, puedo adaptar el mio en función a ese, o diciendome la lógica me sirve, no obstante, he conseguido que mi algoritmo no tenga un tope como antes (antes solo calculaba hasta el 518103) pero tarda siglos en calcular el número 2^31+1.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que falla el enfoque principal. Lo primero es que sabemos que un número primo es siempre impar exceptuando el número dos. Con esto en mente vemos que el código que muestras estás tratando de calcular tambien si los pares son primos por lo que está tardando más tiempo:

```
unsigned long int cont;
for(cont=0; cont<max-1; cont=cont+1){
    // cuando cont es PAR se está comprobando si es primo
    primes[cont] = is_prime(cont+2); //1 si es primo 0 si no
}
```

Para mejorar este punto tendría que ser así:

```
unsigned long int cont;

primes[2] = 1 // El 2 es primo
for(cont=1; cont < max; cont=cont+2){
    primes[cont] = is_prime(cont); //1 si es primo 0 si no
}
```

Ahora si la optimización se busca también para memoria pues ya sabemos que dado una cantidad de números N existen como máximo N/2 números primos que serían todos los impares y posibles candidatos. Entonces nuestro array en memoria se reduciría a la mitad.
Pero si en tu código sólo usas de forma auxiliar el array de primos calculados ya que los calculas y luego simplemente los imprimes, puedes prescindir del uso de memoria este modo y mismo resultado aunque más eficiente:

```
unsigned long int cont;

printf("Números primos existentes entre 0 y %d\n", max);
printf("1 2 ");
for(cont=3; cont < max; cont=cont+2){
    if (is_prime(cont)== 1)  //1 si es primo 0 si no
       printf("%d ", cont);
}
return 0;
```